# Is it possible to filter by date in Excel 2008 for Mac?

Tags: excel, macos, excel-2008

An example of the data:

```
date,letter
2/2/2012,a
2/3/2012,v
1/1/2011,c
```

Is it possible to use filters to select only the data from 2011?

Comment: Probably, but why would that be a programming-related question?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in Excel 2011 for Mac. I post this answer so you can check if it works for you as well. Let me know the result -- I will remove the answer if it does not work.

If you choose to filter By Cell Value, you can select a filter for All Dates in the Period, and 2011 is waiting for you to be checked. Here is a screenshot that I took to illustrate the situation:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely possible for 2011, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it for 2008

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are text, then filtering to select ends with `11` should serve. If your dates are Date/Time serial numbers and you are using the 1904 date system then a Custom AutoFilter of is greater than or equal to 39082 And is less than 39447 should work.

If neither suits then, if you data is in columnA starting with a label in A4, then the following formulae may suit:

in A1 copied across to B1:  `=$A4`
in A2: `>=1/1/11`
in B2: `<=31/12/11`

in conjunction with Sort & Filter, Advanced, Filter the list, in-place, a List range: $A$4:$A$n and Critera range: `$A$1:$B$2`.

Where `n` is the number for the last relevant row.